# How to combine class cases?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, slick

I am using play framework and slick, play framework uses a case map in the form validation but there are values that I don't need validated as they are not inputed by the user, e.g. the ID & Date which is done is provided on the backend.

**By the end** I would like to have a class case like this, to provide to Slick and use with my Table.

```
case class Order(id: Long, order: String, date: Date)
```

For Play's Form validation I would provide a seperate case class:

```
case Class inputableOrder(order: String)
```

Can I then create the Order class that will grab the variables from inputableOrder and added it the Order class?

```
case class Order(id: Long, date: Date) // <- some way to add the variable from inputableOrder?
```

I'm just trying to prevent repetition but I still need two different case classes (one for form validation and another for working with the database).

Is there a way to modify an existing case Class , remove a variable or modify a variable type?

Comment: I think you're using the word "type" where you mean "variable", "field", "property", "parameter", or "argument". In you first example, Order, Long, String, and Date are types, and id, order, and date are variable names.

Comment: @Tim Mostly I'm worried for the Type of the parameter, as I can't receive a checkbox post as a List (even if I do a for each and the insert the Int) because the case class variable type is Int and Play Form validation will only accept the post as an Int, unless I use a different case class with a different Type from the one being used by Slick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have several options here:

1. Make `InputableOrder` a part of `Order`:

   ```
   case class InputableOrder(order: String) // ...
   case class Order(input: InputableOrder, id: Long, date: Date) // ..
   ```

   This is probably the most idiomatic solution. But it can be inflexible if you later realize that `InputableOrder` needs something that shouldn't be in `Order`.
2. Make `Order` a subclass of `InputableOrder`. In this case there is some code repetition when passing arguments to the superclass, and the superclass can't be a `case` class, so you have to declare it as a regular class and create an extractor yourself:

   ```
   class InputableOrder(val order: String) // ...
   object InputableOrder {
     def unapply(o: InputableOrder): Option[String] = Some(o.order);
     // if you have more than one constructor arguments, return
     // a tuple like Option[(String,String)] etc.
   }

   case class Order(override val order: String, id: Long, date: Date)
     extends InputableOrder(order) // ...
   ```

   Again, the same problems can arise as with the previous point.
3. Make the classes distinct and create helper methods to convert between them. The choice depends on your design, but I find this solution to be most flexible:

   ```
   case class InputableOrder(order: String);
   case class Order(order: String, id: Long, date: java.util.Date) {
     // An additional constructor to use when converting from Inputable:
     def this(other: InputableOrder, id: Long, date: java.util.Date) =
       this(other.order, id, date);
     // Update this instance with `other`:
     def this(that: Order, other: InputableOrder) =
       this(other, that.id, that.date);

     def toInput = InputableOrder(order);
   }
   ```

   This way you can create an `Order` from an `InputableOrder` just by supplying the missing fields and vice versa. You need to write these helper methods/constructors once, but using them is then easy.

   You can also use implicit methods such as

   ```
   implicit def toInput(other: InputableOrder): Order = other.toInput;
   ```

   to make things even easier.